# Is the deleted answer harmful in this post?

Tags: discussion, answers

In [How do I prevent "Local Items" Keychain from locking?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/325724/how-do-i-prevent-local-items-keychain-from-locking)

One of the answers was flagged as basically causing data loss and then substantially edited. If you do have 10k reputation, you may see the post or the edits. Please use the answer to discuss the merit of bringing the answer back and/or undeleting. If you can't see it - please ask for the contents to be copied here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be reopened/undeleted provided that the author...

1. cite the sources he used (and referenced) so it can be determined which versions of macOS/OS X it supposedly worked with
2. instead of deleting the file/folder, a command to back it up (i.e. `mv foobar foobar.bak`)

I personally tested (on a VM) this and while it didn't crash my system I did lose login data (wasn't important...just reverted to a previous snapshot).  As it stands, I would down vote the answer and leave a comment to back up the folder prior to attempting.

Comment: Thank you very much for testing and considering this. I've undeleted the post and added a brief - please backup before you mess with keychains warning and also trimmed the meta. We may need to augment it with links and fixing steps....

Comment: @bmike I think you misunderstand the issue with the "answer": It results in a complete loss of all relevant data. That's like saying the way to remove a slightly musty smell from some documents is to burn them. Nothing can be gained from preserving it.

Comment: @orome - We delete when posts don't fit the qualification of being an answer.  Their relevance, quality and usefulness are subjective and should be voted on as such.  The bottom line is, it's an *answer*.